# What is the structure of the Thread Environment Block on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows

What is the structure of the Thread Environment Block on Microsoft Windows?

Comment: FS selects the Thread Environment Block, not the PEB.  It is undocumented but has been reversed-engineered for a couple of Windows versions.  Google is the best place to ask, repeating it here doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having where you think you need to access the PEB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run windbg
Setup symbol path for microsoft public symbol server
Type

> dt ntdll!_PEB

Comment: Can I use another Windows DLL instead of ntdll?